# For which functions/distributions X, $S(\mathbb R) \ast X \subset \ell ^{1}({\mathbb Z})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, convolution, schwartz-space

Let $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^d)$ (Schwartz space) and define $f_k(x) =f(x-k) \ (k\in \mathbb Z^d)$ (translation of $f$).

> Question: For which  kernel $h:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb C,$  one can expect that $$\|f_k\ast h \|_{\ell ^1} = \sum_{k\in Z^d} |f_k \ast h(x)|\leq  C$$ ( $C$ is  some constant independent of $k$ but can be dependent on $f$ and $h$). (where  * is the convolution in $\mathbb R^d$.)

Side notes:  I'm interested in the singular kernel $h(x)= \frac{1}{|x|^{\gamma}} (\gamma >0)$

Comment: $x$ dependence?

Comment: Thanks.  No it should be independent  of $x$.